# access element of a list view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've followed this example to create a filtered listview: 
[list view with gridview](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/).
Now I want to access to an element of my table. Actually my table is declared as follow:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
              Grid.Row="2" Name="Children" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ID"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
```

C#

```
List<Child> items = new List<Child>(); 

... 

foreach (string ID in IDS) items.Add(new Child() {ID=ID}); 

Children.ItemsSource = items
```

How can I access to the selected item and get the ID field? I know that could seem a trivial question but I'm a bit frustrated after hours of attempts.

Comment: What were your attempts? Share some code that you have tried.

Comment: The `SelectedItem` property of the listview is the selected data item. Bind it to a viewmodel property. If for some reason you want to do this in code behind, you'll need to cast it to the actual type in the event handler. How are you populating the listview?

Comment: The list is populated in the following way: List<Child> items = new List<Child>();
...
                foreach (string ID in IDS)
                    items.Add(new Child() {ID=ID});
                Children.ItemsSource = items;  Where Child is a class containing the ID field.

Comment: Please put code in the question. Nobody can find it or read it in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I access to the selected item and get the ID field?

You could cast the SelectedItem property of the ListView to the type (User or whatever your class is called) where the ID property is defined, e.g.:

```
User selectedUser = Children.SelectedItem as User;
if(selectedUser != null)
{
 var id = selectedUser.ID;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much. I modified your code to fit my case as follow: Child selectedUser = _childchoicepage.Children.SelectedItem as Child;
                if (selectedUser != null)
                {
                    ID = selectedUser.ID;
                }.  I didn't know about as... syntax, I'm quite new in this world

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

**Xaml**

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="listView_Click" Grid.Row="2" Name="Children" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ID"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**Code behind.cs**

```
private void listView_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var item = sender as ListViewItem;
    if (item != null && item.IsSelected)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your code:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
         Grid.Row="2" Name="Children" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn 
                    Header="ID"  
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding   ID}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

In your ViewModel you should have a property `SelectedId`, with the same type of your ID column.

When user selects an ID in your ListView, the selected id will be in you property `SelectedId`.